# Verifying that binomial distribution is a valid PMF.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to figure out if X ~ Bin(n,p) is a valid PMF. In other words, I need to show that:

$$\sum_{x \in X} {n\choose x} p^{x} (1-p)^{n-x} = 1$$

Comment: This is the binomial theorem. Do you want to prove the binomial theorem? There are proofs in wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to show that:

$$\sum_{x}\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x} = [p + (1-p)]^n= 1^n = 1$$